# rails 4 - role based authorization from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization

I have recently started learning rails and had to develop an application with three roles: user(admin), student, instructor. I wrote the following code myself. but the problem is that it makes the role of all active users similar to the most recent login. For example, if admin was logged in and later a student logs in and then if admin refreshes her page, she will also become a student. What i should change in my code to fix this problem? And if it is not possible to implement it like this way, suggest me how i should fix this problem. thanks.

here is my users_controller code:

```
def login
if session[:user_id]!=nil
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end
end
def attempt_login
if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
    found_user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first
    if found_user
      authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if authorized_user
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome! You are LoggedIn"
        session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
        return
      end
    end
    found_student = Student.where(:username => params[:username]).first
      if found_student
        student_id = Student.authenticate( params[:username],params[:password])
        if student_id
          flash[:notice] = "Welcome! You are LoggedIn"
          session[:user_id] = student_id
          redirect_to(:action => 'student_index')
          return
        end
      end
    found_instructor = Instructor.where(:username => params[:username]).first
      if found_instructor
        instructor_id = Instructor.authenticate( params[:username],params[:password])
        if instructor_id
          flash[:notice] = "Welcome! You are LoggedIn"
          session[:user_id] = instructor_id
          redirect_to(:action => 'instructor_index')
          return
        end 
      end
    flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/Password combination."
    redirect_to(:action => 'login')
end
end


def logout
flash[:notice]="Logged out"
session[:user_id] = nil
redirect_to(:action => "login")
end
```

and here is my application_controller.rb code

```
def require_login
  unless session[:user_id] or config.my_config
      flash[:notice] = "You are not Logged In"
      redirect_to :root
      return false
  else
    return true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're sharing the same session key `session[:user_id]` to store the ID of `User`, `Student` and `Instructor`. How do you differentiate between the three kinds of logged in users?

It's possible that if a logged in `Student` visits the `instructor_index` path, then the student's ID would be used to load a `Instructor` with the same ID, and a view for an instructor would be rendered. I don't see any code to indicate otherwise.

I would have expected such a system to store both a `session[:user_id]`, and a `session[:user_type]` to ensure that it's possible to exactly identify the logged in person.